# How to interpret 'hcitool afh' (AFH map)

Tags: bluetooth

Sometimes, I have problems when I use Wlan and Bluetooth concurrently. I wanted to check if they use the same frequencies and found out that I can check the current AFH-map with `hcitool afh`.

The result looks something like

```
user@device:~$ hcitool afh xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
AFH map: 0xff4f28000000f0fe0000
```

So now, what does that mean, where is that documented?

Comment: If this is a wifi/bt combo card, add the results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` to the question as your issue may be fixed by changing the default parameter for bt coexistence.  I can't find where to decode the info from that command either

Comment: Yes, it is a combo card, it is an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 card.
Next question: What is "Bluetooth coexistence"? I have already found this approach (with bt_coex_active=0) and I believe that it has helped but I am trying to understand, not only to find/copy a solution.

Comment: Sometimes the default parameter doesn't work as it is supposed to minimize the interference between wifi and bluetooth but it doesn't always work.  It seems that bluetooth uses 70+ frequencies and hops from channel to channel

Answer (score 2):

*I just came across this question looking for the meaning of "AFH map". Although the question is quite old, I'd like to share my findings.*

There are (at least) two different mechanisms that help to reduce the interference between Bluetooth and WiFi:

### 1. Adaptive Frequency Hopping (AFH)

Bluetooth devices transmit on 79 different channels, spaced 1 MHz apart between 2,402 MHz and 2,480 MHz. During data transfer, the sender changes the used channel very quickly in a pseudo-random order ("hopping sequence") to reduce the chance of interference caused by other radio services using the same frequency range. The receiver knows the sequence and "hops" the channels synchronously with the sender.

The basic principle of AFH is simple: Channels with known interference are simply left out of the hopping sequence. The AFH map simply tells both communication devices which of the 79 channels are good to use and which to leave out. The AFH map consists of 80 bits (20 hex digits) corresponding to the 79 channels (and 1 reserved bit).

Channels usable for Bluetooth have the corresponding bit in the AFH map set. That is, the more "1" bits you see, the less interference is there and consequently the more throughput your Bluetooth link will have.

AFH was introduced with Bluetooth 1.2. You can find more details e.g. in the  [Bluetooth 5.0 Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=421043) (search for "AFH channel map" in the PDF file).

### 2. Bluetooth Coexistence

While AFH covers any (probably external) source of interference, BT coexistence is designed to minimize interference caused by a Bluetooth interface and a WiFi interface that are co-located in the same device (i.e. laptop, smartphone). Basically there is a wire running from the WiFi chip to the Bluetooth chip. Whenever the WiFi chip is transmitting a frame, it tells the Bluetooth chip to "shut up for a moment" until the WiFi transmission is over.

Over time, different, more elaborate variants of this basic scheme were developed (2-wire, 3-wire, unidirectional, bi-directional etc.)